# Changing name to method into controller (Swagger)

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, webapi

I'm new to Swagger and Web API. I created a Web API project with a simple controller called PrimeCalculator.

```
public class PrimeCalculatorController : ControllerBase { 

   [HttpGet]
   public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
    //stuff 
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
   }

}
```

So my method in Swagger looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, there is one method with a get call. So far so good, but now I want to change method name. I found this:

```
[Http(name="newMethodName"]
```

However, the method's name stays the same. I don't know if I'm missing something. Any tutorial to learn or help is welcome.

Results after changing the method name (nothing changes):
[image: Results]

Comment: I don't think you should care about method name. Endpoint is the thing you want to look at. I'm not really sure what are you trying to achieve but if you want to have a different endpoint you should do `[HttpGet('NewMethodName')]` and then you will have your new endpoint which would be `/api/PrimeCalculator/NewMethodName`

Comment: Yes , but the endpoint didnt change i mean is : .../api/PrimeCalculator, ait shoud be .../api/PrimeCalculator/NewMethodName, am i wrong?

Comment: Try this `[Http(name="newMethodName")]` -> `[HttpGet("newMethodName")]`

Comment: Thanks it changed perfectly, answer with that

Comment: But i still dont understand why using the name tag it didnt work

Comment: As far as I know, `name` attribute is not the same. You can try to use `template` instead, I believe it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241535/discussion-between-kestutis-ramulionis-and-hesolar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Http(name="newMethodName")]` -> `[HttpGet("newMethodName")]`

Comment: While this may answer the question, you can still improve it by following the S.O guideline here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer